# What kind of data do I pass into a Django Model.save() method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say that we are getting POSTed a form like this in Django:

```
rate=10
items= [23,12,31,52,83,34]
```

The items are primary keys of an Item model. I have a bunch of business logic that will run and create more items based on this data, the results of some db lookups, and some business logic. I want to put that logic into a save signal or an overridden `Model.save()` method of another model (let's call it `Inventory`). The business logic will run when I create a new `Inventory` object using this form data. Inventory will look like this:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    picked_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name="items_picked_set")
    calculated_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name="items_calculated_set")
    rate = models.DecimalField()
    ... other fields here ...
```

New `calculated_items` will be created based on the passed in items which will be stored as `picked_items`.

My question is this: is it better for the `save()` method on this model to accept:

- the request object (I don't really like this coupling)
- the form data as arguments or kwargs (a list of primary keys and the other form fields)
- a list of Items (The caller form or view will lookup the list of Items and create a list as well as pass in the other form fields)
- some other approach?

I know this is a bit subjective, but I was wondering what the general idea is. I've looked through a lot of code but I'm having a hard time finding a pattern I like.

**Clarification:**

OK, so the consensus is that it should go into a different function on the model, something like `inventory.calculate(...)` which will then create everything, do the business logic, etc... That's good to know. My question remains: where is the best place to look up the form data into db objects? Should the caller of this function convert primary keys to database models or should the model methods accept primary keys and do it themselves? It's something that I want to do the same way project-wide.

**Clarification 2:**

OK so now there is some disagreement as to wether overriding `save` is ok or not.

When you get a form submission for a simple CRUD type operation, you pass the models and values as arguments to `Model.objects.create(...)` or override `save` or use signals or whatever.

I think the core of my question is this:

If the form submission has related models used for business logic, then you need to write some business logic into your model layer. When you do this, where should it go and should that method accept a list of objects or a list of id's? Should the model API's accept objects or id's?

Comment: I'm not totally aware of why you dont't want to use a signal, and if so i guess there will be instances of your Item objects passed, which should answer your question?

Comment: I'm open to using signals for this. In the past, I simply pass everything needed into the Inventory.objects.create() method. That works nicely for simple cases.

Here, when I create a new Inventory model object I associate it with a bunch of existing models *and* I create a set of related models based on some business logic. I'd *like* to push that logic into the model layer. In your opinion - what method should that business logic code go into, and who should be responsible for looking up the foreign keys? The caller of the business logic or the method itself?

Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

OK so the first two answers I got have now been contradicted by others. I've been researching this and I'm going to take a stab at answering it myself. Please vote if you think this is correct and/or comment if you disagree with my reasoning.

- Methods on models should accept objects and lists of objects, not ids as int/long or lists of id's or anything like that. This is because it will probably be called from a view or form and they have access to full objects from `cleaned_data` dict. The `create()` method on manager classes are another example where django itself accepts objects.
- The caller of the model layer methods should look up and convert the id's into full objects.
- You can override `save()` but if you do, you should be careful to accept `args` and `**kwargs`
- If the models span applications, you should consider signals instead of overriding `save`
- Don't try to get clever overriding the model manager `create` method. It wont get called if the view layer creates a new object and saves it. If you  need to do extra processing before the save, you can override `save` or `__init__` or catch a signal. if you override `__init__` you can check for a pk to determine if it exists in the db yet or not.

I'm going to put my create code in a separate method for now until I figure out which of the techniques I like best.

I think this is a good set of guidelines for adding methods to the model layer. Anything I missed?